# Deleting Rows if a Cell Starts with a Predefined Value

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I need some ideas on how to develop an excel VBA to eliminate rows that have a cell within it that begins with a value of "27".

```
Sub filtersearch()

Dim filtersheet As Worksheet
Dim I As Integer
Dim FinalCell As Long

Set filtersheet = Sheet3
FinalCell = filtersheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

filtersheet.Select
    For I = 7 To FinalCell
    If Left(someRow.Cells(8).Value, 2) = "27" Then
    Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, 18)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

Basically, I want the entire row to delete from Column **B** through **R** if the 8th column's cell value starts with "27".

With this current code, I receive a Run Time Error 424 and an Object Required, tried a few troubleshooting techniques by editing the code in a manner that I thought would fix it, but to no avail.

Thanks as always.

Comment: I think you're on the right path, but you need to step backwards through your loop if you're deleting cells - `For I = FinalCell to 7 Step -1`

Comment: Or have logic that deletes the row and resets the FinalCell

Comment: you aren't setting "someRow" to anything, hence the error

Comment: That will really help when I get to that point, and I appreciate the input, but for now I just need to get it to run through the code.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, perfect, would you mind showing me how to set that as a column length from line 7 to the end? Or do I simply code it as the entire 8th column?

Comment: My answer specifies this.  Cells(row, column) lets you look at a single cell and evaluate the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
If Left(Cells(I, 8).Value, 2) = "27" Then
```

And also, as suggested in the comments:

```
For I = FinalCell to 7 Step -1
```

Comment: That is downright perfect, but it only deletes the first few rows. So lets say the first row of my results contains "90", if I change the code to delete rows with "90" itll delete those first few rows, but will not delete anything afterwards.
So lets say I have these in that column:
9055
9055
8501
9055
Itll delete the first two rows with that result, but when it hits that "85" it stops and will not delete the next "90" result.
Ideas buddy?

Comment: I was able to create a work around on this, I just changed it from a separate For Next in the coding and applied it to the master portion of the coding to simply filter it out before displaying it. I did use your recommendation of: If Left(Cells(I, 8).Value, 2) = "27" Then so thanks a lot!